# Including size variable when the sample is divided to 3 subsamples based on size

Tags: regression

I am combining two literatures in a research paper. In one literature the sample is divided to subsamples based on size. So they run separate panel regressions for large firms, medium firms, and small firms.

A second literature claims that size is a major determinant of the dependent variable that I am using in my study.

The question is : should I include size as an independent variable when I run separate panel regression for each size group? the size might differ within a group. For example, multinational firms are sup large whereas there are large firms that are domestic.

I hope someone can give me his two cents on this issue to avoid (or defend) any criticism.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents,

I would include the size as an independent variable.
Reason is that it may hold explanatory information even after splitting into different panels.
Guessing that your dependent variable is economics related - lets say company market value.
A company size is for sure a strong indicator to its worth(the bigger the higher) so you want to include it in the analysis.
But, since a 10 employees size difference mean very different things in small companies and in large corporate the panels split reduced some of this variable noise.